# In Java Is it bad practice to pass a method as an argument in another method?

Tags: java

I am in the midst of learning about methods in Java and was curious to know if passing a method as an argument within another method is bad practice. Although I know there are many ways to achieve the same solution there are times in which code written in one way is more efficient than others.

For instance in the code exercise it was asked to create a method with two parameters(name and position)
and create a second method with one parameter(score). Then call both of these methods and display the results using the following score data (1500, 900, 400, 50).

My solution was written as follows:

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayHighScorePosition("Fred",calculateHighScorePosition(1500));
    displayHighScorePosition("Ted", calculateHighScorePosition(900));
    displayHighScorePosition("Jen", calculateHighScorePosition(400));
    displayHighScorePosition("John",calculateHighScorePosition(50));
    }
    public static void displayHighScorePosition(String name, int highScorePosition) {
        System.out.println(name + " managed to get into position " + highScorePosition + " on the high score table");
    }
    public static int calculateHighScorePosition(int score) {
        int position = 4;
        if(score >= 1000) {
            position = 1;
        } else if (score >= 500) {
            position = 2;
        } else if (score >= 100) {
            position = 3;
        }
        return position;
    }
}
```

This displayed the same output as what was expected by the exercise, but the code written in the exercise was

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int highScorePosition = calculateHighScorePosition(1500);
    displayHighScorePosition("Fred", highScorePosition);

    int highScorePosition = calculateHighScorePosition(900);
    displayHighScorePosition("Ted", highScorePosition);

    int highScorePosition = calculateHighScorePosition(400);
    displayHighScorePosition("Jen", highScorePosition);

    int highScorePosition = calculateHighScorePosition(50);
    displayHighScorePosition("John", highScorePosition);

    }
    public static void displayHighScorePosition(String name, int highScorePosition) {
        System.out.println(name + " managed to get into position " + highScorePosition + " on the high score table");
    }
    public static int calculateHighScorePosition(int score) {
        int position = 4;
        if(score >= 1000) {
            position = 1;
        } else if (score >= 500) {
            position = 2;
        } else if (score >= 100) {
            position = 3;
        }
        return position;
    }
}
```

Does it make a difference? i.e. is one a better way to write or will I run into issues down the road when the code becomes much more complex?

Comment: Your code probably works, the code written in the exercise does not even compile. So yes, it makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing another method as a parameter, you're passing the *return value* of a method as a parameter, which is a totally different concept.

Anyway, the second example (apart from being syntactically wrong since you keep re-declaring a variable instead of just re-assigning a value to it) is just more verbose for no apparent gain, in this case.

It would make sense if you then used any of those declared variables someplace else down the method.

Comment: Okay I understand now and appreciate your explanation. thank you very much